# How can I escape a Ruby symbol with quotes only if needed?

Tags: ruby, symbols

IRB and Rails console both have a nice way of outputting symbols that only quote-escapes them when necessary. Some examples:

```
1.9.3p194 :001 > "@test".to_sym
 => :@test 
1.9.3p194 :002 > "@Test".to_sym
 => :@Test 
1.9.3p194 :003 > "@123".to_sym
 => :"@123" 
1.9.3p194 :004 > "@@_test".to_sym
 => :@@_test 
1.9.3p194 :005 > "test?".to_sym
 => :test? 
1.9.3p194 :006 > "test!".to_sym
 => :test! 
1.9.3p194 :007 > "_test!".to_sym
 => :_test! 
1.9.3p194 :008 > "_test?".to_sym
 => :_test?
1.9.3p194 :009 > "A!".to_sym
 => :"A!" 
1.9.3p194 :010 > "@a!".to_sym
 => :"@a!"
```

How would you do this yourself, so that you could do:

```
puts "This is valid code: #{escape_symbol(some_symbol)}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest and best way to do this is via Symbol's inspect method:

```
1.9.3p194 :013 > puts "This is valid code: #{"@a!".to_sym.inspect}"
This is valid code: :"@a!"
 => nil 
1.9.3p194 :014 > puts "This is valid code: #{"a!".to_sym.inspect}"
This is valid code: :a!
```

You could look at the [sym_inspect(VALUE sym) method](http://rxr.whitequark.org/mri/source/string.c?v=1.9.3#7424) in string.c in Ruby 1.9.3 that does that, if you're curious.

So, even though you don't need another method to call inspect, this would be the simplest implementation:

```
def escape_symbol(sym)
  sym.inspect
end
```

Here's my attempt at implementing with a few regexs, although I'd suggest using inspect instead if you can:

```
def escape_symbol(sym)
  sym =~ /^[@a-zA-Z_]@?[a-zA-Z_0-9]*$/ || sym =~ /^[a-z_][a-zA-Z_0-9]*[?!]?$/ ? ":#{sym}" : ":\"#{sym.gsub(/"/, '\\"')}\""
end
```